# Unable to create user in WSO2 IS via SCIM2 API with external claims

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Im trying to create user with external claims, but something wents wrong.
I added my claims to scim2-schema-extension.config, to external claims and local claims, but API's response for my request is:

```
{
"schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
],
"detail": "Error in adding the user: testoviy22@mail.ru to the user store.",
"status": "500"
```

}

In logs i have

```
: ERR_13735_ELEMENT_FOR_OID_DOES_NOT_EXIST ATTRIBUTE_TYPE for OID comment does not exist!]; remaining name 'mail=testoviy22@mail.ru'
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3280)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3205)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2996)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_bind(LdapCtx.java:452)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_bind(ComponentDirContext.java:299)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.bind(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:217)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.persistUser(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:312)
... 73 more
```

[Local claim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzpZ3.png)
[External claim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn2TV.png)

Request sample:

```
{
"name": {
  "familyName": "Zubenko",
  "givenName": "Michael"
},
"password": "qwerty",
"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User": {
  "comment": "test"
},
"userName": "testoviy22@mail.ru"
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are using an LDAP server as your primary userstore, and that server doesn't support the attribute named "comment"
Refer to the note in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/extend/provisioning/extend-scim2-user-schemas/#map-the-custom-claim

> You can use the word "customClaim" (or any other preferred word) as
> the Mapped Attribute only when using a JDBC userstore because JDBC
> userstores will automatically create a new attribute if it does not
> already exist in the user store. **However, If you are using LDAP or
> Active Directory, you will have to use an attribute that exists in the
> user store already**.

Change the mapped attribute of the local claim to some valid attribute in the LDAP schema

Comment: We are using read_write_ldap_unique_id, i think its default for WSO2 IS.
A couple of days ago we added some external claims with mapping to local claims, and it works great.

Comment: Can you check the mapped attributes of those claims? default LDAP server in WSO2 IS doesn't have a attribute called "comment" in the schema

Comment: Mapped attributes is ogrn and inn, user store is PRIMARY

Comment: Maybe i can add attribute to the default LDAP server's schema?

Comment: You can follow https://technospace.medium.com/introduce-custom-attributes-to-default-schema-of-wso2-embedded-ldap-server-e7a575f52691 to add custom attributes to the default schema or any other possible approach

Comment: btw, as a quick fix to verify the changes, you can update the mapped attribute to an existing attribute in the schema, but not used in the IS server claims in your flows

Comment: Hello again! I tried to update the mapped attribute to an existing attribute in the schema, and its work great. Then i tried to change schema like in guide https://technospace.medium.com/introduce-custom-attributes-to-default-schema-of-wso2-embedded-ldap-server-e7a575f52691 but attributes that i added still not recognizing by the LDAP server. Maybe there is some function to reload schemas on the server?

Comment: Problem solved with migrating to JDBC userstore